# Bubble sorting problem does not change the input array

Tags: c++, arrays

Function is not working. The array is not sorted it just prints the way I insert integers. Can someone please help me?

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main() {
  int n;

  cout << "Enter size of array" << endl;
  cin >> n;

  int A[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "enter integer" << endl;
    cin >> A[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "Sorted Array: ";
    cout << A[i] << " ";
  }

  void bubblesort(int A[], int n);
}

void bubbleSort(int A[], int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
      if (A[j] > A[j + 1]) {
        int swap = A[j];

        A[j] = A[j + 1];

        A[j + 1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Learn to use [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and step through your code in the order that it will get executed. You have very very basic issues with your logic. Also, `void bubblesort(int A[], int n);` is a function declaration, not a function call. You should review how to declare and call functions.

Comment: `int A[n];` is not standard C++, because standard C++ doesn't have variable length arrays. Your code only compiles because of a non-standard compiler extension. Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your code works actually not like the one you copied ! this what you should change

```
//first you call the function of sorting before you display the array after being sorted :)
//secondly  the way you used void bubblesort(int A[],int n); this just a redeclarion & not calling the function

//this is how you call it 
bubblesort(A,n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

{

cout<<"Sorted Array: ";
cout<<A[i]<<" ";

}
```